# Bedeutung von "so gut wie + [Adjektiv]"

Tags: meaning

Zum Beispiel

> Das ist so gut wie ausgeschlossen
>
> Der Sieg ist so gut wie sicher

Ist das nur eine Verstärkung oder drückt ein bestimmtes Gefühl aus?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_gut_wie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"So gut wie" ist weder eine Verstärkung noch drückt es primär ein bestimmtes Gefühl aus. Vielmehr ist es eine leichte **Abschwächung**, gleichbedeutend mit
 *fast, annähernd, beinahe* oder auch *fast, aber nicht ganz* oder - in manchen Verwendungsweisen - *praktisch*, *faktisch* und *im Grunde*.

Hier sind weitere typische Verwendungen:

> Das Projekt ist so gut wie tot.

Formell ist das Projekt noch in der Umsetzung, doch praktisch gesehen läuft da nichts mehr.

> Die beiden sind so gut wie verheiratet.

Sie verhalten sich als wären sie ein Ehepaar, aber sie sind es juristisch gesehen nicht; vermutlich steht die formelle Hochzeit kurz bevor.

> Liselotte hatte die Marmelade so gut wie eingekocht.

Der allergrößte Teil der Arbeit war getan, nur noch wenige Schritte waren zu tun (z.B. die Gläser abkühlen lassen und dann wegräumen).

> Fritz hatte seine Hausaufgaben so gut wie fertig.

Das meiste hatte er geschafft, nur noch wenige Minuten Arbeit standen bevor.

Erstaunlicherweise finde ich den Ausdruck im Duden (Universalwörterbuch) nicht. Dabei war ich so gut wie sicher, dass er dort zu finden sei.

Comment: Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gut#Bedeutung3b

Comment: @Pollitzer. Aha. Also doch. Hatte mich auch gewundert. Nun bin ich ob meiner Dudenleseunfähigkeit natürlich so gut wie blamiert.

Comment: Wenn du deine Antwort anpasst, können wir die Kommentare löschen.